# SSDT projects and managing Integration tests with known data

Tags: sql-server, integration-testing, sql-server-data-tools

I'm migrating over to SSDT for schema control of the DB structure for a large project with accompanying database. This project already has hundreds of integration tests inside of it that are in various states of brittleness. Many of these use what I would call "known data" to perform the integration tests with. The tests are relying on this data to be there for them to run successfully.

In the past, we've done a 1:1 copy of our integration test database for testing in feature branches, but i'm not wild about this process as it adds bloat to the server.

Using SSDT, is there a way to incorporate this "known data" into either a SSDT project, or a process that can be used to copy after the fact? I already have post-deploy scripts that load seed data into the system (types and the like), so I could put all known data there, but this could be dozens of extra sql files to potentially manage so i'm not wild about it.

Due to the complexities and the amount of known data, using the application sitting on top of the DB to insert it is not practical.

I was thinking about exploring a bacpac option, but before doing that wanted to see if there were any other ways people have managed integration testing of feature branches with known data in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could take:

1. Use backups/snapshots
2. Integration tests / test data in a separate .sqlproj / dacpac
3. Setup data as part of your tests

**1. Use backups/snapshots**

You could get a database in a known state and then use backups or snapshots. I am not a great fan of this as you always need to keep your base up to date or every now and then refresh it.

**2. Integration tests / test data in a separate .sqlproj / dacpac**

This is what I would usually do for unit tests (integration tests, for me, are normally in the language of the app that calls the database).

I would have a separate .sqlproj in my solution that has a "Same Database" reference to the main project. Put into this the integration tests and the Post-Deploy.sql for the test seed data.

If you have multiple files use ":r" imports to include those and *also* use an ":r" import to include the post-deploy from the main project as when the publish happens, dacpacs that are referenced do not have their pre/post-deploy scripts executed.

If you haven't used references like this before you deploy the test project and /p:IncludeCompositeObject=True

**3. Setup data as part of your tests**

This might be harder if you already have a large suite but I would normally advise that as part of the setup for each test that you get the data in a state that you know it is right for that test.

This way it stops any brittleness from running tests in different order etc.

I haven't looked at bacpac's for this, that might be an interesting way to deal with it as well.

Comment: Mulling this over for a while, but really #3 is the right way to do things here. You have to take the hit initially to re-do all of the tests, but long term the man hours saved not having to maintain a known data set and the code around applying it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you copy all of the data between databases in order to perform your integration testing.

If that is correct, you can:

1. Create stored procedures in a separate schema to populate your tables.  For example dbo.MyTable would be seeded by seed.usp_MyTable, or;
2. Create stored procedures in a separate database to populate the tables, again using an intelligent naming convention.

For both options, a master stored procedure can be used to execute all seed procedures.

Benefits of both are:

- All stored procedures are source controlled, ensuring the history of
  test data is captured.
- It is very simple to programmatically identify seed data coverage
  as each table will have a stored procedure with a matching name.
- It is very simple to initiate the seed process as part of a
  deployment, just include a post-deployment script or SQL task to execute the master seed procedure.
- Seed data procedures can be used as an additional regression test
  to check for source drift when columns or datatypes change.

There are pros and cons for each approach:

1. all seed procedures are part of the same database as the
   tables they reference.  This simplifies the SSDT project as no
   external references are need.
2. different seed data can be leveraged for different
   environments.  An external reference to the data table project is
   needed, but a different seed project can be created for each
   environment.

Answer (score 1):

**BULK INSERT**

The fastest way to get the static data for testing I've found so far is to use "BULK INSERT" from pre-populated data files in the post script. The main problem was that I needed to provide exact files path to the BULK INSERT. However you can use publish variables for that. This solution is the fastest way to get the data and it performs much much better than INSERT/MERGE statements.

**INSERT/MERGE**

If there is no so much data then INSERT/MERGE in the post scripts work well. There is already implemented stored procedure that can help to generate these statements. You can check it [on github](https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge).

**tSQLt**

It is not really related to the actual question, but I strongly advice to use [tSQLt framework](http://tsqlt.org/) for testing. It is not integration but unit testing, but with proper usage you will not need pre-populated data and it will be working on any database.